# Why does $\tan\left(x ^ {1/x}\right)$ have a maximum value at $x=e$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

> Why does this function,  $$\tan\left(x ^ {1/x}\right)$$
>   have a maximum value at $x=e$?

[image: Graph]

Comment: Do you mean: Why does the maximum occur at $x=e$ ?

Comment: Yes my apologies for any confusion

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maxima of a continuous function can be found when the derivative is equal to zero. In this case,
$$
f(x) = \tan{(x^{\frac{1}{x}})} \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad f'(x) = \left(-x^{1/x - 2}\right) \left( \ln{x}-1\right)\left(\sec^2{\sqrt[x]{x}} \right)
$$
(you can ask Wolfram Alpha for this.) For this to be zero, the only option is $\ln{x}-1 = 0 \Rightarrow x= e^1 = e$.

Answer (score 3):

Here $\tan$ is a red herring.  For any strictly monotonous $C^1$-function $g$ it holds that $x^{1/x}$ and $g\bigl(x^{1/x}\bigr)$ share their extrema at the same values.

To get the extrema in our case replace $\tan$ by $\ln$ and happily find them.

Comment: This is also true! Thanks, this gives me a better understanding of this.